# rtl8139 driver in modern linux kernels - is it included?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, drivers, realtek

I need to support the realtek rtl8139 network card - is this included in modern (> 3.0) linux kernels? do I have to load any modules or install anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Realtek is a fairly standard adapter and has been in the mainline kernel for a long time. The driver/module is `8139cp.ko`. The device should be auto-detected on a modern Linux distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Drivers 8139cp and 8139too.

Answer (score 3):

The driver has been included in the standard kernel distribution for many years.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your Linux kernel vendor(Linux distribution). But most likely it has one. To check `grep`/`zgrep` your `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` / `/proc/config.gz` / `.config` for string `8139`:

```
rbtz@linux:~$ grep 8139 /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_8139CP=m
CONFIG_8139TOO=m
CONFIG_8139TOO_PIO=y
# CONFIG_8139TOO_TUNE_TWISTER is not set
CONFIG_8139TOO_8129=y
# CONFIG_8139_OLD_RX_RESET is not set
```